# Prove that $\iint\limits_ {[0,1] \times [0,1]} \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ is not integrable

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I have to prove that the following integral does not exist:

$$\iint \limits _{[0,1] \times [0,1]} \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy .$$

I think I can use Fubini's Theorem, ie. if I show that iterated integrals are not equal to each other, then the corresponding double integral can't be integrable, because otherwise it would be "counter example" to Fubini's Theorem. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Some remarks: (1) Your integrand changes sign if you swap $x$ and $y$, so by symmetry, the integral must be zero if it exists. (2) You can restrict your attention to the set $\{(x,y);x\geq0,y\geq0,x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ (the integrand is nice outside it) and use polar coordinates. (3) It seems that the iterated integrals don't exist (I haven't checked) but they should if the integral did exist. (4) The integral exists in a principal value sense and is zero then, but this is probably not what you want.

Comment: I believe $\int_{x=0}^1\left(\int_{y=0}^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy\right)dx=\pi/4$ and $\int_{y=0}^1\left(\int_{x=0}^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dx\right)dy=-\pi/4$. So from Fubini theorem double integral doesnt exist. Is that right? Note that $\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}\arctan(y/x)$

Comment: I can't do those integrals in my head, but you can always ask if Wolfram alpha agrees with you. http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: I didnt want you to check integrals, but the general idea. If I proved that those integrals exist and are not equal, then the double integral doesnt exist (from Fubini). Is that caorrect reasoning?

Comment: Yes, the reasoning is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The region $\{(x,y): x\ge y\ge 0,\;x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ is contaied in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and the integrand is nonnegative there. Furthermore, we can easily parametrize it in polar coordinates:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^1r\frac{r^2\cos2\theta}{r^4}drd\theta$$

But $1/r$ is not integrable at $r\in(0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is not exactly right. The function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ is not integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the unit square $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ (so it does not fulfill the hypothesis of Fubini's theorem), but the integral
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy\,dx$$
**does** exist, since:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy = \frac{1}{1+x^2} $$
hence:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
However, it is straightforward to check that:
$$ \frac{\pi}{4}=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy\,dx\neq \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy = -\frac{\pi}{4}. $$
The integral that is not defined is:
$$ \iint_{(0,1)^2} f(x,y) \,d\mu $$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the unit square.

Comment: You are right! I meant exactly that. Didnt notice i copy-pasted iterated integral.